# Reassign int to const int?

Tags: c, constants

I'm reading through a C code base, and I found a snippet that looks something like  this:

```
void foo(int bar) {
    const int _bar = bar;
    ...
}
```

The author then uses _bar throughout the rest of the code. Why is this done? Is it an optimization, or is there some other reason?

Comment: I can't see any advantage over declaring the parameter `const` in the first place.

Comment: @Oli: making non-pointer parameters `const` can be seen as leaking implementation details...

Comment: @Christoph: It doesn't affect the outside world, though.  You could declare your functions with non-const params in your public API, and then use `const` in the definition.  (This is exactly what I do, in fact.)

Comment: @Oli: correct - in fact, I was just about to add that to my answer, but I needed to look up the relevant section of C99 first, which is the last, parenthesized sentence of a somewhat lengthy paragraph (which is the excuse I used when I found out that what I believed to be undefined behaviour is actually legal ;))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably the author does this to avoid accidental assignment.

If the param is unchanged from the function input, the author could put the const in the param signature, as in `void foo (int const bar) { ... }`.

Comment: But the author could just have declared the parameter `const` in the first place.

Comment: Well, the code is in C, so references aren't available, unless I *really* don't understand C. If this is to avoid reassignment, why wouldn't the stub be "void foo(const int bar)"?

Answer (score 6):

> The author then uses _bar throughout the rest of the code.

If `_bar` is used through out and not using the function parameter, I would qualify the function parameter by `const`.

```
void foo( const int bar )
{
     // use bar but modifications to bar itself are not allowed.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As C passes arguments by value, there's no difference between

```
void foo(int bar);
```

and

```
void foo(const int bar);
```

as far as calling code is concerned.

Thus, *const*-qualifying a non-pointer parameter arguably makes an internal implementation detail part of the public API.

Another solution would be to declare the function without `const` in the header and only add it to the definition (as Oli Charlesworth suggests in the comments as well), ie

```
// in header file
extern void foo(int bar);

// in source file
void foo(const int bar)
{
    // ...
}
```

which is - as far as I know - legal due to the last sentence of C99 6.7.5.3 §15.

Comment: You make some good points, but I disagree with "const-qualifying a non-pointer parameter arguably makes an internal implementation detail part of the public API." Why? Because of this: `void foo (int const bar) { int baz = bar; /* use baz now */ }` That is, the user has no way of knowing what is going on, even with a const param.

Comment: @trinithis: you're still leaking the information that for whatever reason, the argument needs to be `const`, which *is* additional information as the default for parameters is not to be `const`; you're correct that you can't derive from that how the parameter will be used, but that only strengthens the fact that the `const` qualification is useless as far as calling code is concerned...